# Aligning over a character

Tags: css

In my contact information i have a few lines looking like this.

```
Phone: 123 456
Web site: page.eu
```

I'd like to create a vertical alignment over the semicolons. One way to do that, i think, is to use two different divs, float them to the left and set the contents of one to be right aligned and the other to be left aligned. is there a neater way, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed width floating divs or tables (but don't brag about it because it is not best practice)

http://jsfiddle.net/pXScG/3/

Comment: Tables are frowned upon because you end up with a boxy layout that's not flexible.  If you want your data in a grid they're the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this appears to be a list of contact information, I'd suggest first using a list-element, and then two spans to contain, and align, the text:

```
<ul id="contact">
    <li><span class="contactMethod">Phone</span>:<span class="contactInfo">123 456</span></li>
    <li><span class="contactMethod">Web site</span>:<span class="contactInfo">page.eu</span></li>
</ul>
```

With the CSS:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}

span.contactMethod {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
}

span.contactInfo {
    width: 65%;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pXScG/).

Answer (score 1):

There are no semicolons (;) in the example; I presume you mean colons (:). What you have is a table of data, so an HTML table is the most appropriate structure here, and it gives the desired rendering if you simply right-align the first column. However, it is best to set paddings too:

```
<style>
th { text-align: right; font-weight: normal;  padding-right: 0.3em; }
</style>
<table>
<tr><th>Phone: <td>123 456
<tr><th>Web site:<td>page.eu
</table>
```

Comment: Of course. I meant colon. I'm by principle avoiding tables since the old days when it was abused as a substitute for CSS'ing. But you're actually making a very compelling case. I guess i could use the table.